# How to fix program and file association?

Tags: file-association, gentoo, gnome3, content-type-association

My system is Gentoo amd64, with Gnome3. I found some of the files/actions are associated with the wrong program.

> e.g.: when I plug in my usb drive, the associated program is RawTherapee, a raw image processing tool, instead of the nautilus.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried right clicking -> properties -> open with?

Comment: Definitely I can do that. But that is less ideal. I would like to have the most used program being associated with the files/actions.

Comment: It will hold for the whole extension, not just that file

Comment: Thanks. But this only works for files. I am also having trouble with devices, like when plugging in a USB disk. :)

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/ask

Comment: Why did you accept soandos's answer below when it only works with files and not devices? That seems an odd choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Associating most used types of files with applications in Gnome 3 is done through

*System Settins >> System >> Details >> Default Applications*

In the same pane you have *"Removable Media"* where you can *"Select how media should be handled"*.

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this is by right clicking -> properties -> open with...